# How to disable logging for Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to reduce the logging of `RestTemplate`.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(dataToBeSenttoVM, headers);

            log.info("something");

            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

When the statement is executed it prints a Response. I am doing a lot of API calls using this, and this is creating a lot of logging noise in my console.

Is there any way I can reduce or disable the logging for this?
I only want to avoid logging in this part of the code not the whole application.

Using Log4j's LoggerManager with following:

```
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %5p %-70.70(%logger:%L){70}  %m%n
logging.level.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Comment: What is your logging configuration?

Comment: Set your `spring.logging:level.org.springframework.[...]` to something different than *DEBUG*.

Comment: I'm using log4j @Aakash

Answer (score 0):

Increase the minimum logging level of `RestTemplate` in your application.properties file, e.g., to `ERROR`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate=ERROR
```

Or, if you're using an application.yml file:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate: ERROR
```

Comment: I tried doing that but that didn't work.

Comment: In that case, we need more information: your current application config & more of your code.

Comment: I'll update my code

Comment: Using log4j's LoggerManager

Comment: Your config includes `logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG`. Have to tried to remove this of move it up before the other line?

Comment: yea i tried that. doesn't work